# Regex not matching the whole word in htaccess rule

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to work out why this doesn't work:

```
   RewriteRule ^search/(.*)-more([0-9]+).html /cgi-bin/search.cgi?bool=and&substring=0&query=$1;nh=$2 [P,L]
   RewriteRule ^search/(.*).html /cgi-bin/search.cgi?bool=and&substring=0&query=$1 [P,L]
```

Example usage:

- http://foo.com/search/test.html
- http://foo.com/search/test-more-2.html
- http://foo.com/search/test%20extra.html
- http://foo.com/search/test%20extra-more-2.html

The first 2 work fine - `test` gets passed along to the query param.

However, on the 2nd one - it gets cutoff at `%20` ... so instead of passing `test%20extra`, all it passes is `test`

I've compared a similar rule I'm using on another server, and it works fine with (.*) as the selector... so I'm not sure whats different here!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Argh... I got it! It wanted NC,L and not P,L as the flags. So:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)-more([0-9]+).html /cgi-bin/search.cgi?bool=and&substring=0&query=$1;nh=$2 [P,L]
   RewriteRule ^search/(.*).html /cgi-bin/search.cgi?bool=and&substring=0&query=$1 [P,L]
```

Needed to be:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)-more([0-9]+).html /cgi-bin/search.cgi?bool=and&substring=0&query=$1;nh=$2 [NE,L]
   RewriteRule ^search/(.*).html /cgi-bin/search.cgi?bool=and&substring=0&query=$1 [NE,L]
```